# In unity why cannot Instatiate a gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform

I am currently coding in Unity and I am trying to Instantiate a gameObject. The mechanism I'm developing will delete the Image I'm on and load the image underneath, using two buttons ; One to create and one to delete thus giving the effect of moving through a graphical stack.

I have thought about moving the image forward along the z axis so it is out of view, but I have read that the object MUST be instatiated and not Transformed

I have a Rigidbody2d and (2x) 3D Box Collider over the image that has the code. One on the left and one on the right

The delete button works a treat and just to check I do not have a problem with the box collider I have tried the delete code on the other button which also works fine, so I have come to the conclusion that the code is flawed in some respect

My problem is that I cannot seem to recreate the object once it has been deleted, it is my understanding that the object does not have to exist in world space for it to be recreated. If I use the Quaternion Identity I get a few errors about the gameObject being rendered off screen

```
***
          Instantiate(gameObject,new Vector3 (8,-17,11), 
// Removed until I can actually get the image to Instantiate
Quaternion.identity);
***
```

I have also tried

```
***
 Instantiate(gameObject,new Vector (gameObject.transform.position.x -0.08, gameObject.transform.position.y, -0.17, gameObject.transform.position.z, 11), Quaternion.identity);

    }
 }
***
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you removing your object with Destroy? or how?

Comment: Instantiate means you copy an existing object and place it into the scene. You should not delete the parent object that needs to be copied into the scene. You should only delete the copy of the parent object. So you can instantiate the parent object again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to Unity too, but I believe what you need is a Button that Swaps the Sprite image.

Select your Button in the Hierarchy.

In the Inspector:

1. In the Image component, drag in the first Sprite
2. In the Button Component:
3. select the check box Interactable
4. select Sprite Swap in the Transition Drop Down
5. drag your second Sprite to "Selected Sprite"

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to Unity too, but I believe what you need is a Button that Swaps the Sprite image.
Select your Button in the Hierarchy.
In the Inspector:
In the Image component, drag in the first Sprite
In the Button Component:
select the check box Interactable
select Sprite Swap in the Transition Drop Down
drag your second Sprite to "Selected Sprite"